# How Usuage Crc16 ModBus in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, crc

Hello I have algo for crc16 Modbus but I don't know how I will call it and use,

```
CONST table: ARRAY[0..255] OF WORD =
        ($0000,$C0C1,$C181,$0140,$C301,$03C0,$0280,$C241,$C601,$06C0,$0780,
        $C741,$0500,$C5C1,$C481,$0440,$CC01,$0CC0,$0D80,$CD41,$0F00,$CFC1,
        $CE81,$0E40,$0A00,$CAC1,$CB81,$0B40,$C901,$09C0,$0880,$C841,$D801,
        $18C0,$1980,$D941,$1B00,$DBC1,$DA81,$1A40,$1E00,$DEC1,$DF81,$1F40,
        $DD01,$1DC0,$1C80,$DC41,$1400,$D4C1,$D581,$1540,$D701,$17C0,$1680,
        $D641,$D201,$12C0,$1380,$D341,$1100,$D1C1,$D081,$1040,$F001,$30C0,
        $3180,$F141,$3300,$F3C1,$F281,$3240,$3600,$F6C1,$F781,$3740,$F501,
        $35C0,$3480,$F441,$3C00,$FCC1,$FD81,$3D40,$FF01,$3FC0,$3E80,$FE41,
        $FA01,$3AC0,$3B80,$FB41,$3900,$F9C1,$F881,$3840,$2800,$E8C1,$E981,
        $2940,$EB01,$2BC0,$2A80,$EA41,$EE01,$2EC0,$2F80,$EF41,$2D00,$EDC1,
        $EC81,$2C40,$E401,$24C0,$2580,$E541,$2700,$E7C1,$E681,$2640,$2200,
        $E2C1,$E381,$2340,$E101,$21C0,$2080,$E041,$A001,$60C0,$6180,$A141,
        $6300,$A3C1,$A281,$6240,$6600,$A6C1,$A781,$6740,$A501,$65C0,$6480,
        $A441,$6C00,$ACC1,$AD81,$6D40,$AF01,$6FC0,$6E80,$AE41,$AA01,$6AC0,
        $6B80,$AB41,$6900,$A9C1,$A881,$6840,$7800,$B8C1,$B981,$7940,$BB01,
        $7BC0,$7A80,$BA41,$BE01,$7EC0,$7F80,$BF41,$7D00,$BDC1,$BC81,$7C40,
        $B401,$74C0,$7580,$B541,$7700,$B7C1,$B681,$7640,$7200,$B2C1,$B381,
        $7340,$B101,$71C0,$7080,$B041,$5000,$90C1,$9181,$5140,$9301,$53C0,
        $5280,$9241,$9601,$56C0,$5780,$9741,$5500,$95C1,$9481,$5440,$9C01,
        $5CC0,$5D80,$9D41,$5F00,$9FC1,$9E81,$5E40,$5A00,$9AC1,$9B81,$5B40,
        $9901,$59C0,$5880,$9841,$8801,$48C0,$4980,$8941,$4B00,$8BC1,$8A81,
        $4A40,$4E00,$8EC1,$8F81,$4F40,$8D01,$4DC0,$4C80,$8C41,$4400,$84C1,
        $8581,$4540,$8701,$47C0,$4680,$8641,$8201,$42C0,$4380,$8341,$4100,
        $81C1,$8081,$4040);

PROCEDURE CalcCRC16 (p: pByte; nbyte: WORD; VAR CRCvalue: WORD);
VAR i: WORD;
q: pByte;
BEGIN
    q := p;
    FOR i := 1 TO nBYTE DO
    BEGIN
        CRCvalue := Hi(CRCvalue) XOR Table[ q^ XOR Lo(CRCvalue) ];
        INC(q)
    END;
END;
```

7e 00 00 00 00 74 00 5e 01 5a 02 20 70 11 15 20 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

for These Bytes it should response as "  79 B7  "

Thanks in advance everyone and Stack Overflow team!

Answer (score 1):

There are three missing pieces of the puzzle. First, you need to know the initial value of `CRCValue` to pass to `CalcCRC16`. For the Modbus CRC-16, that value is $FFFF, as [found here](http://www.modbustools.com/modbus_crc16.htm) and [here](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.modbus).

Second, you need to know what to compute the CRC over. All of the bytes in your message? A contiguous subset of them? Which subset? For that you will need to refer to some documentation on the format you are using.

Third, how is the CRC stored in the stream? Big-endian or little-endian? So does your `79 b7`, presumably from the stream, mean the 16-bit value `79b7` or `b779`? Again you would have to refer to the documentation.

A search of all possible contiguous subsets of your message turned up neither 16-bit CRC. You may have incorrectly identified the location of the CRC itself in the message.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answer, this my was bad, I'm sorry, 7E first prefix,     so   :     crc from:  00 00 00 00 74 00 5e 01 5a 02 20 70 11 15 20 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                                                                    > b9 79 crc

Comment: So before it was b7. Now it's b9. Which is it? In any case, there is no match for either CRC in either order with any subset of the data.

Comment: Thaks for answering, I find solution of this, http://i.hizliresim.com/2ZB8jE.png , my bad with other prefix i was try..... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Original Code from Sky devil**
-------------------------------
function GetModbusCRC16(const HexData: string): UInt16;
var
Buffer: Array of Byte; //TArray<Byte>;
CRC: UInt16;
Mask: UInt16;
I: Integer;
J: Integer;
begin
SetLength(Buffer, Length(HexData) div 2);
HexToBin(PChar(HexData), Buffer, Length(Buffer));

CRC := $FFFF;
for I := Low(Buffer) to High(Buffer) do
begin
CRC := CRC xor Buffer;
for J := 1 to 8 do
begin
Mask := 0;
if ((CRC / 2) <> (CRC div 2)) then
begin
Mask := $A001;
end;
CRC := (CRC div 2) and $7FFF;
CRC := CRC xor Mask;
end;
end;

//--------------------------------------------------------- Swap result
//Result := CRC; <- comment this
// Swap lo/hi
Result := ((CRC and $FF) shl 8) + (CRC shr 8);
end;


var 
C: UInt16;
S: string;

begin
C := GetModbusCRC16('01030400000060');
S := IntToHex(C,4); // <- $FA1B
end;


**VB version original from internet**:
------------------------------------

Sub getCRC16_Modbus()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim mask, i, j, nC, Crc As Integer
    Dim c As String
    Dim txt As String

    txt = "01030400000060"

    Crc = &HFFFF ' crc mit $ffff initalisieren

    For nC = 1 To Len(txt) Step 2
        j = Val("&H" + Mid(txt, nC, 2)) 'im HEX-Format
        Crc = Crc Xor j
        For j = 1 To 8
            mask = 0
            If Crc / 2 <> Int(Crc / 2) Then mask = &HA001
            Crc = Int(Crc / 2) And &H7FFF : Crc = Crc Xor mask
        Next j
    Next nC

    txt = Hex$(Crc) 'Checksumme

    Label1.Text = txt

End Sub
```

Comment: Answers are most useful when they provide a short explanation of how and why the code presented answers the question.